# What folder on android does show as a media device?

Tags: music, google-play-music

When I connect my phone to my car via USB it says connected as media device.  Then when I go to browse with my car nothing is in the folder.

I use Google play music and know the folder it caches my downloaded playlists.  I want to make a symbolic link to that folder from the folder my car is seeing.  Does anyone know what folder is mounted by default?  Or maybe a better way to play music in my car?

HTC One M8 Converted Google PLay Edition.  2014 Mini Countryman w/out MINI Connected.

Answer (score 1):

First, that depends on the protocol. AFAIK, when using PTP, only the `DCIM` folder (with your photos) is shown, while in MTP mode, it should be your entire SD card(s).

Second, I doubt whether a symlink would work here – at least not when it points to the internal storage (below `/data`, where *Play Music* usually puts its stuff).